# How to check certain value of column and skip certain row

Tags: python, csv

[image]

```
import ctypes
import csv

with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
  reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
  next(reader)

  for row in reader:
     if(int(row[3])>=5):
         print(row)
         mymessage = 'A message'
         title = 'Popup window'
         ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, mymessage, title, 0)
     else:
    continue
```

I currently have the above csv file and code. However, when I do `print(row)`,

```
['string1','00','00','21','00'..]
['string2','00','00','84','00'..]
['string3','00','00','21','00'..]
['string4','00','00','21','00'..]
               .
               .
               .
['string7','00','00','21','00'..]
['string8','00','00','84','00'..]
['string9','00','00','15','00'..]
['string10','00','00','84','00'..]
['       ','precision','recall','f1-score','support'..]
```

It prints like above.

```
with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
  reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
  next(reader)

  for row in reader[1:-8]:
         print(row)
         if(int(row[3])>=5):
              mymessage = 'A message'
              title = 'Popup window'
              ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, mymessage, title, 0)
         else:
            continue
```

So in order to ignore the red part of the picture, I thought I could skip the last eight lines through the above code. But there's a problem.

My two problems with using this are:

1. I don't know the total number of lines, because
2. the number of strings1 to n changes every time when I write CSV file.

As I tried, I would like to remove the unnecessary lines below while checkinging whether each value in a particular column is greater than 5.

Comment: You can use `next()`

Comment: Are the eight last lines fixed? You mentioned that only the lines with `string1` to `stringn` changes with every csv

Comment: @QuagTeX Yes, the form is fixed and the value changes every time. Because I use the `classification_report` function [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html#examples-using-sklearn-metrics-classification-report).

Comment: @PCM I know `next(reader)` skips the first row(and so I already used it.). Can you tell me more details? Do I have to use like `next(row[:-8])` this after `next(reader)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the number of lines of your csv before you import it into python.

```
lines = sum(1 for line in open('data.csv'))  # gives you the total number of lines without loading csv
```

Then you can import it without the last 8 rows (like the example with pandas below)

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=';', decimal='.', header=0, skipfooter=8)  # loads the csv without last 8 rows
```

or you load it with your code without the last 8 rows.

Connecting your code it should be:

```
lines = sum(1 for line in open('data.csv'))  # gives you the total number of lines without loading csv
with open('data.csv') as csv_file:

  reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
  next(reader)

  for row in range(lines-8):  # using the number of lines here. It doesn't even load the last 8 lines
         print(row)
         if(int(row[3])>=5):
              mymessage = 'A message'
              title = 'Popup window'
              ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, mymessage, title, 0)
         else:
            continue
```

Comment: I already knew that there was a `skipfooter` property in Pandas after some searching. Could you please let me know more specifically how to incorporate your code with the code I have? I've seen a lot of solutions like yours, but I don't know how to combine them because I'm not using pandas. I'm now using `with open` in python

Comment: @Emma Lim I edited my answer. This should do the work

Comment: I think this answer doesn't make sense. `for row in range(lines-8)` means row now has a int type. However, The behind code `if(int(row[3])>=5):` needs row[3], which is an array. Therefore, of course, errors occur.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the answer. We can make the csv reader read the certain range of rows through `itertools.islice`.

```
from itertools import islice

with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
   reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
   #next(reader) We don't need this anymore beacause we read only certain rows.

   for row in islice(reader, 0, 10): #reads the row from 1 to 11
       print(row)
     if(int(row[3])>=5):
          mymessage = 'A message'
          title = 'Popup window'
          ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, mymessage, title, 0)
     else:
        continue
```

So I used this code.

```
lines = sum(1 for line in open('data.csv'))

for row in islice(reader, 0, lines)
```

In case your total csv rows are not fixed, you can use the above code like this.